# Custom username in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I want usernames (created using an algorithm) to be automatically assigned to users and want to allow login using both this username and email address. How do I do that in Keycloak?

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use rest api to create user. This way you can use alghoritm to generate username. Documentation is here:
   https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/10.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource
2. In the realm settings go to Login tab and enable Login with email
   [image]